# How to create an random extension where returns multiple of 10?

Tags: c#, function, random

I'm creating a function where returns multiple of 10?

```
public static int NextInt(this Random rnd, int min = 0, int max = 1)
{
    if (rnd == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("rnd");
    if (min >= max) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    var delta = max - min;

    return min + (int)(rnd.NextDouble() * delta + min);
}

public static int MultipleOf10(this Random rnd, int minZeros = 1, 
    int maxZeros = 10)
{
    if (rnd == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("rnd");

    int pow = NextInt(rnd, minZeros, maxZeros);
    return (int)Math.Pow(10, pow);
}
```

I've got doubt about the these two functions. The first one must be similar like Next() and the another one must return multiples of ten.

Can you point me where I fix it? Because I'm almost sure of that.

Comment: mutiple of 10, or power of 10? They're very different.

Comment: Than the first one works like Random.Next(), and the another must return multiples of ten like.. 10, 1000, 100, 100000..

Well, power of..

Comment: You ask for a 'fix'. That implies there is an error. But we are left guessing what that error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the last line of `NextInt()` should be

```
return min + (int)(rnd.NextDouble() * delta);
```

Or:

```
return min + rnd.Next(delta);
```

Or even better:

```
return rnd.Next(min, max);
```

Also, you should keep in mind that the upper bounds of `Random` methods are exclusive. So, if `rnd.NextInt(i, j)` should return numbers between `i` and `j` *inclusive*, you probably want to change the computation of `delta` to:

```
int delta = max - min + 1;
```

or if you used the last option above, change it to:

```
return rnd.Next(min, max + 1);
```

Comment: Or perhaps even better: `return rnd.Next(min, max + 1);` (though I suppose to be safe, make sure that max < Int.MaxValue first)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that overload.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the `MultipleOf10` method like so:

```
public static int MultipleOf10
        (this Random rnd, int minZeros = 1, int maxZeros = 10)
{
    if (rnd == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("rnd");
    if (minZeros >= maxZeros) throw new InvalidOperationException();

    return (int)Math.Pow(10, rnd.Next(minZeros, maxZeros));
}
```

And you don't need the `NextInt` method.